# Knockoutjs: How to filter observableArray by param

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/Gr3fT/1/

How to filter `personRoles` by `role` property?
Each list must have only own `role` items.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This function works (based on http://knockoutjs.com/examples/animatedTransitions.html :)

```
get: function(role) 
{
    return ko.dependentObservable(function () 
    {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.personRoles(), function(item) 
        {
            return item.id == role;
        });                


    }, viewModel); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might help you.

This example basically used for filter observable array by passing input parameters at the key up event.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25241564/3929314